# jQuery. Using json data on remote server fails

Tags: jquery, json

I am working with json data together with jQuery. It works perfectly fine when using a local json file, but shows just a blank page when using a remote json file from another server (even when using a complete URL from my own server).

This works:

```
$.getJSON('9.json', function(data) {
```

Does does not work:

```
$.getJSON('http://beta.ambadoo.com/users/9.json', function(data) {
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

same server, same port. use jsonp.

Answer (score 4):

> As of jQuery 1.2, you can load JSON
>   data located on another domain if you
>   specify a JSONP  callback.

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON

**[The Solution :)](http://bob.pythonmac.org/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/)**

Comment: The link listed as "The Solution :)" is dead ... :(

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/).

Seems that the magic is doing the '&callback=?'.

> Beginning with version 1.2, jQuery has had native support for JSONP calls. You can load JSON data located on another domain if you specify a JSONP callback, which can be done using the following syntax: url?callback=?.

Comment: I tried this now and it still does not work: $.getJSON('http://beta.ambadoo.com/users/9.json&callback=?', function(data)

Do I need to do anything else. Is the API supporting JSONP?

Comment: Try this URL: 'beta.ambadoo.com/users/9.json?callback=?', The ampersand is if you pass other parameters...

Comment: Tried that too and unfortunately still a blank page. Could it be that the API does not support JSONP? How can I check?

Comment: what does "?callback=?  do?  I have a WCF service, I now have configured to allow GET requests, but I haven't been able to hit the server to get info with Javascript or jQuery.  and this "?callback=?" baffles the heck out of me.  I can get a response typeing the url directly into a browser, but I just get the string "Error" returned back.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246781/jsonp-calling-wcf-returning-error